# How do I pull from the same column in the db to 2 different columns with different data on the front end?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, one with employee names and numbers, and one with duties requested.

Table A has data about the employees, that is their names and payroll numbers.

Table B has tasks that have been requested by different departments/employees

The employees offer different services across the organization- for instance IT employees offer IT support, electrical engineers offer electrical maintenance services and all the other employees are co-dependent on different departments for different services.

So, I need to pull data on the employee who requested the task and the name of the employee assigned the task -who are two different employees- on the front end.

This is the code I am using and it displays the same names on both the requester column and the assigned person column.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM bf_maintenance_orders 
  JOIN bf_employees h 
    ON h.id = bf_maintenance_orders.orderBy
  JOIN bf_employees z 
    ON z.id = bf_maintenance_orders.scheduledStaff

echo '<td>'.$numrows2['staff_name'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$numrows2['category'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$numrows2['staff_name'].'</td>';
```

Comment: *I need to pull data on the employee who requested the task and the name of the employee assigned the task* These 2 names are not related - so you need 2 separate copies of employees table, each copy will "decrypt" one of these columns to the name. `FROM bf_maintenance_orders mo INNER JOIN bf_employee e1 ON mo.requester_id = e1.id INNER JOIN bf_employee e2 ON mo.assigner_id = e2.id`

Comment: There's no tableA or tableB here. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Tip: Never use evil `SELECT *`. Instead always name, qualify, and (if necessary- as in this case) alias only the columns you actually want returned

Comment: @Akina thanks for the feedback, but what I want is to use this data from the same table instead of having 2 tables with the same data,, might you know how to? because all this employees offer the services to each other

Comment: Ща course this is possible, but it will give more complex slow query.

Comment: Kindly give me like a run through, or a guide please